# npm extremely slow on Windows on a network drive

Tags: windows, node.js

I have unpacked Node.js 19.0.0 from https://nodejs.org/dist/v19.0.0/node-v19.0.0-win-x64.zip to a Windows PC because I cannot use the installer due to having no admin rights on the machine. The node folder resides on a network drive and executing `node --version` takes around 900 ms  but executing `npm --version` takes 15 seconds. Why is npm so slow? Does it read the whole node_modules folder before reporting? `npm.exe` is ~60 MB in size, so I estimate the speed of the network drive to be ~67 MB/s, so it seems as if npm.cmd reads in around 1 GB.
When I move the node folder to a local drive it is much faster, but I want to understand why `npm.cmd` reads in so much data for the version command.

Comment: The raw throughput is not the problem/limit. Latency is.

Comment: @DanielB: Ah you mean the number of files? But why does "npm --version" need to read so many files?

Comment: No idea. NPM depends on over 200 packages in total. It _is_ the Node ecosystem we’re talking about!